# Change the background of TabControl Header in C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change the header background color of TabControl in C# Winform.
Now It looks like this. I have owner-drawed  the Control. But, cant change the background.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476957/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-tabcontainer-tab-bar-in-c

Comment: That never helps,,, Its just changing the background color of buttons,  I have already done that,,, 
I want to change the color of white portion (Behind the tab buttons,.. )

Comment: Check This Out Try Editing And using Code  http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2012/12/custom-tab-control-in-vbnet.html

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for this.

Comment: @HighCore Cant roll back my 1 year old project :D

Comment: @YesudassMoses no, but you could integrate rich, beautiful WPF content inside your existing winforms application using the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
I used this control http://dotnetrix.co.uk/controls.htm
It has a TabControl2 that supports the transparent background for TabControl.
Now it looks pretty good.

[image]

Comment: I thought it supported some **source code**, but if it's just a compiled library, we have tons of better controls out there, source code will help us learn better.

Comment: yess. But another stylish control there in codeproject. Its written in C++. But it makes the form crash always. This one is simple and just like the normal TabControl with some added features.